# ASP.NET web API identity External login redirect

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using ASP.net webAPI identity for Facebook login , I have angularjs application

when I call

```
MainURL + 'api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true'
```

I don't want to return to web API page , instead I want Facebook to redirect me back to my angularJS app so I did this :

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ExternalLogins")]
    public IEnumerable<ExternalLoginViewModel> GetExternalLogins(string returnUrl, bool generateState = false)
    {
        IEnumerable<AuthenticationDescription> descriptions = Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();
        List<ExternalLoginViewModel> logins = new List<ExternalLoginViewModel>();

        string state;

        if (generateState)
        {
            const int strengthInBits = 256;
            state = RandomOAuthStateGenerator.Generate(strengthInBits);
        }
        else
        {
            state = null;
        }

        foreach (AuthenticationDescription description in descriptions)
        {
            ExternalLoginViewModel login = new ExternalLoginViewModel
            {
                Name = description.Caption,
                Url = Url.Route("ExternalLogin", new
                {
                    provider = description.AuthenticationType,
                    response_type = "token",
                    client_id = Startup.PublicClientId,
                    redirect_uri = new Uri("http://localhost:6263/com.html").AbsoluteUri,
                   // redirect_uri = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, returnUrl).AbsoluteUri,
                    state = state
                }),
                State = state
            };
            logins.Add(login);
        }

        return logins;
    }
```

redirect_uri = new Uri("http://localhost:6263/com.html").AbsoluteUri,

but browser give me an error 
[image]

response from service is :

```
/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Facebook&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=localhost%3A6263%2Fcom.html&state=j0y0wF0yhvA_tzqbJo0GijCecqfbNWT0vLQiXxcHDqM1
```

Answer (score 0):

Im sure this is late. Take a look at your url, it has a double slash (//)